Flutter - Backing up application data
In my app I have a backup screen for the data I have in the app.
I work with an ObjectBox, and I have a button that generates a .zip backup file with .mdb files and another button where I can select this file to load the backup into the app.
However, this method is somewhat flawed, what I want to know are other ways to do this, how could I backup my app data?
Waiting for a different idea

Natan!

https://isar.dev/


https://pub.dev/packages/isar

import
    await Isar.open(...)
  
export
    await isar.copyToFile('/natan-backup.isar');

happy coding! :)
